# point A record to the ip of the trafficmanager azure?

Tags: domain-name-system, azure

I would like to redirect the apex root of the domain, ( naked domain ) to the azure virtual machine. It makes sense i would use a traffic manager to balance the traffic load, and redirect users to the cloudservice. But then i have to point the A record to a fixed ip, which i dont know how to find that in traffic manager? So how do other people point their A records to an IP?

Answer (score 2):

You can only use CNAME with Traffic Manager, not A records. So, you'd add a CNAME mapping to `yourapp.trafficmanager.net`.

Full details are [here](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/web-sites-traffic-manager-custom-domain-name/).

Comment: and then what happens with people going to  http://domain.com?

Answer (score 0):

Traffic manager does not support the use of Apex roots, as you cannot create a CNAME for the domain root. There is a uservoice request to support this [here](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/217313-networking/suggestions/5485350-support-apex-naked-domains-more-seamlessly).

Some people have had sucess with using an Alias record for the domain root, which does work as it does allow co-existance with other records on the domain, but your DNS provider needs to support it.

Comment: yes, i already voted for that request. And notice that its 2 years old, and nothing yet! Thats how big companies work, the bigger the worse.